# IO String not expected in mysql-simple execute

Tags: mysql, haskell

I'm using `mysql-simple` and when I build the program, I get the following error:

```
No instance for (Database.MySQL.Simple.Param.Param (IO String))
  arising from a use of ‘execute’
In a stmt of a 'do' block: num <- execute c q v
```

I guess it's the `IO String` which `mysql-simple` doesn't want in its parameters.

What is the ideomatic way to handle this?

**Edit:** I tested it with `""` and it worked fine.

Comment: What are the types of `c`, `q` and `v` in your code? I'm guessing your  `q` does *not* have type `Query`, as it's supposed to have. How is `q` defined?

Comment: @gspr `c` is the Connection, `q` the Query and `v` a Tuple of values to replace the `?`s. In the tuple is the `IO String`.

Comment: How is `q` defined then?

Comment: @gspr `let q = "<query>" :: Query`

Comment: Alright, then `v` is the culprit. How is it defined?

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mysql-simple-0.2.2.5/docs/Database-MySQL-Simple.html#v:execute, in my case `(h)` where `h` is of type `IO String`

Comment: Ah, well, obviously, that won't do. `IO String` is not an instance of `QueryParams`. Look for yourself - define `v` to have one of the types listed as instances of `QueryParams` in the docs you just linked to.

Comment: I know, but I don't know how to do that with an `IO String`. It's not listed here: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mysql-simple-0.2.2.5/docs/Database-MySQL-Simple-Param.html#t:Param

Comment: Although your question has been answered, I suggest you seriously consider looking into understanding monads. Knowing the difference between `IO String` and `String` is essential if you want to program in Haskell.

Comment: @gspr I've understood IO but I couldn't find the error. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `v` is an `IO String`, i.e. an IO action *producing* a `String`, and `execute` expects something of type `String`, you first have to ”run” `v`. So instead of

```
num <- execute c q v
```

you have to write

```
str <- v
num <- execute c q str
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. By the way, is it possible to execute it inline?

Like `num <- execute c q (<- v)`?

Comment: The beginner-friendly answer is “no”. You can write `v >>= execute c q`, though. But as @gspr says: There is some background here worth learning.